# Do the following 2 pieces of code consume same memory

Tags: c++

Consider 2 C++ codes :

```
int main()
{
int j;
cin>>j;
return 0;
}
```

AND

```
int main()
{

for(int j;;)
// Do Something

for(int j;;)
// Do Something

for(int j;;)
// Do Something
}
```

Do these 2 pieces of code consume same space in memory or does the declaration of j again and again increases space.

Please Help.

Comment: This isn't specified in the C++ specification, it's an implementation detail that is left for the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extent of a variable is from where it starts, to where it is last used.

The compiler may use different slots of memory (or register) for j, because it is easier to enumerate each new variable into a new place.

The compiler may use the same slot of memory (or register) for j, because it can write faster code.